# htaccess hide subdomain url parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

This is my url is shown at the moment;

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/post?id=152&title=titleofpost
```

This is my htaccess as shown below;

#### To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

#### To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

#### Blog subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

How can I show the url as;

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/post/titleofpost
```

or

```
http://blog.example.co.uk/titleofpost
```

Thanks